# Create new project on VS using Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to create a blank app(XAML) and I can not see the create a new project on the menu. Do I need an extension? Or is it because I am using a Mac? Thank you

[image]

Comment: VSCode is just an editor (like Notepad), so it does not have a project system (like Visual Studio or Xcode). So for different kind of frameworks you might use their corresponding tools, such as `npm init` or `dotnet new`.

Comment: I think you meant to download `Visual Studio`, not `Visual Studio Code`